# I want to add required(*) with every required label

Tags: jquery, css

I have a requirement to make required with a red asterisk mark. I have required class with the labels which are required fields in my application. There are so many forms in the application. I was trying this with jquery using the below code.

```
  $(".required").each(function(){
   $(this).prepend("<span class='red'>*</span>");
  });
```

Could any one help me to apply this using css. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Then please show your html so that we can help without guessing.

Comment: *"... I have required class.."* `required` class or `required` attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just CSS?

```css
label.required::before {
  content: '*';
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="input1" class="required">Label One</label>
  <input type="text" id="input1" />
</form>
```

Comment: The `::before` pseudo-element is not supported in IE8 or earlier. So be sure your clients or customers are using half-decent browsers ;o)

Comment: @ne1410s this is only true for the double-colon syntax. You could still use `:before` as fallback if required: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Answer (score 3):

Although @isherwood's answer meets your requirements, here is a fun alternative method:

Use the `required` attribute on your `input`s instead of a class. Reverse the `label` position by means of `float`, and then use `::after` pseudo-element on labels which follow inputs with required attribute set.

***Demo***:

```css
div.form { width: 240px; }
div.form input {
    float: right;
}
input[required] + label::after {
    content: '*';
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
}
br {
    clear: both; }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <input id="i1" />
    <label for="i1">Label: </label>
    <br>
    <input id="i1" required />
    <label for="i1">Label: </label>
    <br>
    <input id="i1" />
    <label for="i1">Label: </label>
    <br>
    <input id="i1" required />
    <label for="i1">Label: </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. HTML5 form validation is better supported with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used something like the following JQuery.  (Although it does depend on the exact HTML in place of course).

```
$(".required").append(
    $("<span>").addClass("red").text("*");
);
```

And then for the css, simply

```
.required.red { color: rgb(255,0,0); }
```

*NB: The color property in CSS can be specified in a variety of different ways.  The rgb approach is just my default preference.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap.. 
Its simple as this..

```
   <label> Label Name <span class="symbol required"></span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you'd like to work with ***static method***, you can implement below:**

```
public static IHtmlContent RequiredLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        if (htmlHelper == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(htmlHelper));
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        
        var viewData = htmlHelper.ViewData;
        var modelMetadata = viewData?.ModelMetadata;
        var metadataProvider = htmlHelper.MetadataProvider;

        var modelExpressionProvider = (ModelExpressionProvider)htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IModelExpressionProvider));
        var modelExplorer = modelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(viewData, expression);
        if (modelExplorer == null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to get model explorer for {modelExplorer}");
        var metaData = modelExplorer.Metadata;
        
        var propertyName = metaData.PropertyName ?? viewData?.ModelMetadata?.Name;
        if(propertyName==null) throw new NullReferenceException("Unable to retrieve property");

        var modelExpression = modelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(viewData,expression);
        var labelText = modelExpression?.Model ?? metaData.DisplayName;

        IDictionary<string, object> attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (htmlAttributes == null)
        {
            attributes.Add("class", "control-label");
        }
        else
        {
            attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            var classAttributes = attributes.Where(x => x.Key == "class").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
            if (!classAttributes.Contains("control-label"))
            {
                attributes["class"] += " control-label";
            }
        }

        var highlightClass = "required required-label-color";

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? Name : propertyName);
        tagBuilder.InnerHtml.AppendHtml($"{labelText} (<span class='{highlightClass}'>*</span>)");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);

        var content = new HtmlContentBuilder().AppendHtml(tagBuilder);
        return content;
    }
```

**If you'd work with *non-stati*c method, you can do as follows:**

```
<label-required for="@Model.Title"></label-required>


[HtmlTargetElement("label-required")]
public class RequiredLabelTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    // Will be used as highlight-class in html
    [HtmlAttributeName("highlight-class")]
    public string HighlightClass { get; set; } = "required required-label-color";

    [HtmlAttributeName("class")]
    public string MainClass { get; set; } = "control-label";

    [HtmlAttributeName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override int Order => -1000;

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    protected IHtmlGenerator Generator { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// An expression to be evaluated against the current model.
    /// </summary>
    [HtmlAttributeName("for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public RequiredLabelTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        Generator = generator;
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (output == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
        }

        var modelExplorer = For?.ModelExplorer;
        var metaData = For?.Metadata;
        var propertyName = For?.Name ?? metaData?.PropertyName;
        var labelText = metaData?.DisplayName ?? propertyName; //For?.Model?.ToString();

        var htmlAttributes = new { @class = MainClass };
        
        TagBuilder tagBuilder;

        if (For != null)
        {
            tagBuilder = Generator.GenerateLabel(
                ViewContext,
                modelExplorer,
                propertyName,
                labelText: labelText,
                htmlAttributes: htmlAttributes);
        }
        else
        {
            tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            {
                tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", Name);
            }
        }
        
        // Do not update the content if another tag helper targeting this element has already done so.
        if (!output.IsContentModified)
        {
            output.MergeAttributes(tagBuilder);
            output.TagName = tagBuilder.TagName;
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

            var requiredMarkTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
            requiredMarkTagBuilder.AddCssClass(HighlightClass);
            requiredMarkTagBuilder.InnerHtml.Append(" *");

            // We check for whitespace to detect scenarios such as: <label for="Name"></label>
            var childContent = await output.GetChildContentAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
            if (childContent.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace)
            {
                // Provide default label text (if any) since there was nothing useful in the Razor source.
                if (tagBuilder.HasInnerHtml)
                {
                    tagBuilder.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(requiredMarkTagBuilder);
                    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(tagBuilder.InnerHtml);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    childContent.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
                    requiredMarkTagBuilder.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
                    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```